V-Text-field type="date" issue Vuetify Javascript
I'm getting an issue with Safari only for displaying initial state of a date
when the view is loaded on Safari, it puts automatically the date of Today, even my initialState is : sell_act_at:"",
this trouble is happening only under Safari Any suggestions or idea how to resolve this ? thanks
here's a playground to test
Must open the playground under safari to see the issue.
Expecting


I'm not sure of solution unfortunately but can point out it's not Vue/Vuetify specific.  It's default behavior on Safari with <input type="date"> element, which v-text-field wraps around.

The date picker interface looks different across web browsers because each browser's rendering engine implements the interfaces differently.
Safari uses Webkit rendering engine and Chromium based browsers uses Blink rendering engine.
A usual workaround for a consistent interface across the different browsers is to implement a bespoke component that composes a text field and date picker.
Vuetify provides such component in the VDateInput component.
I recommend that you consider using this component if you want the date picker interface to be similar across different web browsers.
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="4">
      <v-date-input
        placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"
        v-model="state.sell_act_at"
        variant="outlined"
        color="rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3)"
        bg-color="white"
        base-color="rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3)"
        rounded="true"
        density="compact"
        class="form-input-text"
        append-inner-icon="$calendar"
        prepend-icon="null"
      ></v-date-input>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>

